# The graphs of $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ and $g(x,y)=-x^2-y^2+xy^3$ "are tangent to each other" at $(0,0)$

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions, partial-derivative

Why can we say that the graphs of $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ and $g(x,y)=-x^2-y^2+xy^3$ "are tangent to each other" at $(0,0)$ ?

I have done the following:

The tangent plane at the graph of $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ at $(0,0)$ is:

$$z=f(0,0)+\left[ \frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}}(0,0) \right](x-0)+\left[ \frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{y}}(0,0) \right](y-0)$$

The partial derivatives are:

$$\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}}=2x$$

and

$$\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{y}}=2y$$

We have that: $f(0,0)=0 \\ \frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}}(0,0)=0 \\ \frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{y}}(0,0)=0$

So the equation of the plane that is tangent at the graph of $f$ at $(0,0)$ is $z=0$.

How can we conclude that the graphs of $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ and $g(x,y)=-x^2-y^2+xy^3$ "are tangent to each other" at $(0,0)$ ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two surfaces are tangent at the point $P\in\mathbb{R}^3$
 iff they are both containing $P$ and sharing the same tangent plane at $P$.

equivalently:

The graphs of $f,g\in\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are tangent to each other at $P\in\mathbb{R}^2$ iff they are sharing the same tangent plane at $P$, i.e. $f(P)+\nabla f(P)(X-P) = g(P)+\nabla g(P)(X-P)$, for all $X\in\mathbb{R}^2$

Now, just find the equation of the plane that is tangent at the graph of $g$ at $(0,0)$, exactly as you did for $f$, make sure it's $z=0$, and if so- they are tangent at the origin.

Comment: What does it mean that the equation of the plane that is tangent at the graph of $f$ and at the graph of $g$ at $(0,0)$ is $z=0$ ??

Comment: I added more details. tell me if you need more

Comment: So, the surfaces contain $(0,0)$ because $f(0,0)=0$ and $g(0,0)=0$ and the tangent plane at $(0,0)$ for both functions is $z=0$. So we conclude that the graphs of $f$ and $g$ are tangent at $(0,0)$. Is this correct?? Could I improve something at the formulation?? @avim

Comment: Correct. just don't forget to solve the tangent plane for $g$ same as you did for $f$

Comment: Does the point $(0,0)$ contain at the gragh of $f$ because $f$ is a function $\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, and $f(0,0) \in \mathbb{R}$ ?? @avim

Comment: No. The point **(0,0,0)** contained at ... because $f(0,0)=0$.
My answer wasn't accurate enough, I made a changes.

Comment: Ok... Thank you!! :-) @avim